# Filter by Date range and sum Row values by Column (in Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Do you have a suggestion on how to make a formula for the problem written in the title?

Here is the example so that you can get an idea of the data format:

```
Name,Location,Category,Total views for your listing,Total uniqe page views for your listing,Average time on page (listing),total,Facebook,Reviews,Telephone,Treatment Menu,Get Directions,Book Appointment,Enquiry,Instagram,Date
John,NSW Sydney,Apple,1,1,0:00:12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13/Nov/2018
Mike,NSW Sydney,Orange,1,1,0:00:10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13/Nov/2018
Kenny,NSW Sydney,Pear,1,1,0:00:00,4,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,13/Nov/2018
John,NSW Sydney,Apple,20,1,0:00:12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14/Nov/2018
Chris,NSW Sydney,Orange,1,1,0:02:48,3,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,14/Nov/2018
Stef,NSW Sydney,Orange,10,1,0:07:22,6,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,14/Nov/2018
```

So, the issue is in making a formula that gets put into cells containing numerical values (from D to O), for each of the Name rows.

What it should look like is:

- for John and for 13th and 14th of November, the cell in column B in that row should be 21
- for Mike for 13th and 14th, it returns 1
- for Jenny, which is not on the list, because she didn't have any values in any of the numerical columns for that day (or a group of days), it should return 0

All of these should appear in the "Main Dashboard" sheet, while the data is stored in the "directory statistics" sheet.

The predefined list of all the possible Names, Categories and Locations is in the "customList" sheet. This means that we don't need to search through the whole dataset of all the values for all the dates, but rather only search through the Names in the "customList". "Name" should be the key value that connects values in different dates.

So far, I have tried with this formula:
=Filter('directory statistics'!A2:A,'directory statistics'!$P2:$P=$P2)
It looks for the name column (A) and then returns the value if the date entered (in P2) matches the value in that sheet for the date column (P)

And then I got stuck! :)

Thank you!

Comment: Show what you have tried as a [mcve] and describe why the results are not satisfactory. No one is going to visit that link (which will be dead in an internet moment anyway) so make sure you [edit] the question and repeat any relevant details as formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why FILTER. Assuming `Name` in A1, and Row 1 and ColumnA in `Main Dashboard` set up as in my image, then:

```
=SUMIFS('directory statistics'!D$1:D$7,'directory statistics'!A$1:A$7,$A2,'directory statistics'!P$1:P$7,">="&B$1,'directory statistics'!P$1:P$7,"<="&C$1)
```

in B2 and copied down would appear to me to achieve the results you seek.

[image: SO53305042 example]